# VBA Sendmail via Outlook using cell references

Tags: excel, vba

The code works absolutely fine with the email address and attachment file path typed **directly** into the cell location. When I link the cell reference to another worksheet (i.e., that same cell set = to the reference cell elsewhere), however, it won't send if either of those two aren't directly typed-in. Not sure why, as the other cells have no issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through **.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)**. By this you are excluding formulas from the loop. Reference to other cel is **xlCellTypeFormulas**

So just change it to loop through all cells without restrictions:

```
For Each cell In Sh.Columns("A").Cells
```